# Load and save a large amount of structured data to and from a file c++

Tags: c++, format, file-handling

I have a system that has lots of Blocks of data stored in a vector of structs
The struct looks like this:

```cpp
class Block {
public: 
    Blockheader header;
    uint32_t index;
    std::string hash; 
    std::string prevhash;
    std::vector<tx_data> transactions; 
    uint64_t timestamp; 
    std::string data; 
};
```

I have a file (blocks.bin) which I wish to flush this vector of the struct into periodically and load from this file at startup. 
This is the current file format:

```
"BLK"
index (height)
blockhash
previous block hash
"TXNS"
tx indexes
"ENDTXNS"
timestamp
extra data
"ENDBLK"
```

I attempted at making a function that loaded this into the struct but it was extremely complicated and inefficient. This is the start of the code I was going to use.

```cpp
std::ifstream blockFile(path +"/blocks.bin");
uint16_t readState;
            uint16_t readIndex; 
            Block Blocks;
            for( std::string fileTemp; getline( blockFile, fileTemp ); )
            {
                if (fileTemp == "BLK") {
                    readState = 0;
                    goto Escape;
                }
                if (fileTemp == "TXNS") {
                    readState = 1;
                    goto Escape;
                }
                if (fileTemp == "ENDTXNS") {
                    readState = 2;
                    goto Escape;
                }
                if (fileTemp == "ENDBLK") {
                    readState = 3;
                    goto Escape;
                }
                if (readState = 0) {
                    if (readIndex = 0) {
                        Blocks.height = fileTemp;
                    }else if (readIndex = 1) {
                        Blocks.hash = fileTemp;
                    }else if (readIndex = 2) {
                        Blocks.previousHash = fileTemp;
                    }
                    readIndex++
                                        if (readIndex > 2) {
                        readIndex = 0;
                    }
                }
```

you get te idea of what i was trying to do from that code. Surley there is a libary out theere that can make this more effficent? or am i just aproching this the wrong way (eg should i save it in json format (if so please provide some examples of c++ libarys that are easy to use and understand and have good documentaion & examples))

**NOTE:** I ***Know*** there are questions on here that are asking how to do this however none of them is trying to read such a large block of data from one file containing multiple blocks of data. Please fully read through my question before flagging it as a duplicate (because you'll see why it's not).

Comment: `goto Escape;` seriously?

Comment: I know, the code is seriously awful but it was an original prototype of how I was going to do it not complete code

Comment: From what you show, the inefficiency is likely due to all the string comparisons. Consider using a `std::unordered_map` mapping the string to handler functions. Alternatively, the `.bin` prefix implies this is a binary file, so you could just use a byte to encode the prefix instead - that way the if's could be rewritten as a switch and compiled into a jump table (very efficient).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess there are many libraries for object persistence (search for Object-Oriented-Data-Base). If you want to write your data to a bin file, you could simply write the `save` and `load` functions. Something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

struct Blockheader
{
    void save(std::fstream&) const {}
    void load(std::fstream&) {}

};

struct tx_data
{
    void save(std::fstream&) const {}
    void load(std::fstream&) {}
};

class Block
{
public: 
    void save(std::fstream& output) const
    {
        size_t size;

        // blockheader
        header.save(output);

        // index
        output.write((char*)&index,sizeof(index));

        // hash
        size = hash.size();
        output.write((char*)&size,sizeof(size));
        output.write(hash.c_str(),size);

        // prevhash
        size = prevhash.size();
        output.write((char*)&size,sizeof(size));
        output.write(prevhash.c_str(),size);

        // transactions
        size = transactions.size();
        output.write((char*)&size,sizeof(size));
        for (const auto& transaction : transactions)
            transaction.save(output); // write the save function for tx_data

        // timestamp
        output.write((char*)&timestamp,sizeof(timestamp));

        // data
        size = data.size();
        output.write((char*)&size,sizeof(size));
        output.write(data.c_str(),size);
    }

    void load(std::fstream& input)
    {
        size_t size;

        // header
        header.load(input);

        // index
        input.read((char*)&index,sizeof(index));

        // hash
        input.read((char*)&size,sizeof(size));
        hash.resize(size);
        input.read(&hash[0],size);

        // prevhash
        input.read((char*)&size,sizeof(size));
        prevhash.resize(size);
        input.read(&prevhash[0],size);

        // transactions
        input.read((char*)&size,sizeof(size));
        transactions.clear();
        transactions.reserve(size);
        for (unsigned i=0; i<size; ++i)
        {
            tx_data transaction;
            transaction.load(input);
            transactions.emplace_back(std::move(transaction));
        }

        // timestamp
        input.read((char*)&timestamp,sizeof(timestamp));

        // data
        input.read((char*)&size,sizeof(size));
        data.resize(size);
        input.read(&data[0],size);
    }

    Blockheader header;
    uint32_t index;
    std::string hash = "hash"; 
    std::string prevhash = "prevhash";
    std::vector<tx_data> transactions; 
    uint64_t timestamp; 
    std::string data; 
};

int main()
{
    // write blocks to file
    std::vector<Block> blocks(10);
    {
        std::fstream output("data.bin",std::ios::out|std::ios::binary);
        if (output.is_open())
        {
            size_t size = blocks.size();
            output.write((char*)&size,sizeof(size));
            for (const auto& block : blocks)
                block.save(output);
        }
    }

    // load blocks from file
    blocks.clear();
    {
        std::fstream input("data.bin",std::ios::in|std::ios::binary);
        if (input.is_open())
        {
            size_t size;
            input.read((char*)&size,sizeof(size));
            blocks.reserve(size);
            for (unsigned i=0; i<size; ++i)
            {
                Block block;
                block.load(input);
                blocks.emplace_back(std::move(block));
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks! i will check it out

Comment: @ArielHurdle I compiled it and tested it. It should work.